# k-Nearest Neighbour Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I am implementing the k-Nearest Neighbour algorithm on my smart device in order to recognize human activities from recognition data. I am going to explain how am I going to implement it. Can you guys, suggest me with any improvements on the steps that I am taking and answer any question that I might ask on the way please?

These are the steps:

1. I downloaded a [labelled dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones) which consists of the triaxial acceleration from the accelerometer together with a label describing the activity. I will choose some of the data in this dataset of only those activities which I wish to recognize (in my case walking, sitting, standing).
2. Then I will extract features (average, minimum, maximum, standard deviation from the magnitude acceleration in my case) from every window of accelerometer data (i.e. from every single record in the dataset which contains 128 readings of accelerometer data) in the dataset and I will store these features together with the label of the window (as one record) in JSON format on a text file on the device. Therefore one record/sample in the training data set will consist of: average, minimum, maximum, standard deviation and a label
3. In the classification step, from the collected data I will also have a window of accelerometer data from which I extract the 4 features mentioned above. Therefore I need to compare the 4 features of the collected data with each sample in the training data. How am I supposed to find the similarity between them as one record will contain 4 features?

As a solution to the question in point (3), I was thinking of taking the k-Nearest Neighbours for every feature by calculating the difference between them and then pick out the majority from every feature. What do you think please? Can you propose any optimizations? Thank you :)

Comment: the feature space is 4 dimensions, you probably want to normalize each axis before taking the Euclidean distance in 4D. NOT distance per dimension.

Comment: what do you mean by normalize @Memming

Comment: perhaps you could `zscore`. (Alternatively, you can use Mahalanobis distance instead of normalizing).

Comment: Why isn't the euclidian distance appropriate for this method then?

Comment: 'cause it'll think one feature is more important than others just because of the scale of that variable (it depends on units).

Answer (score 1):

Quite a funny and interesting application ! ;-)

Well, one of the problem of course is to know when to start and stop computing these features, but I guess you already have some solution for this (fixed time window, or push-button...).
You can of course use a knn classifier to do that, but that certainly wouldn't be my first choice, because it's very sensitive to outliers (if your measures get screwed up for a single training session, it will impact forever your next classifications).
So I'd rather go for a Gaussian model:

1. record about 10 to 20 examples (i.e., vectors of 4 values) for each activity
2. compute the mean vector and diagonal covariance matrix for each activity
3. at test time, you compute the Gaussian likelihood that your new observed vector is generated by one of the three Gaussian models, and you choose the activity with the largest likelihood.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem differently. I would take a lot of samples over a longer period of time (say 1 week) and then find clusters in them. After that the user would be able to label the clusters whenever the current measurement is close to one of the clusters. The number of clusters should be limited to a few activities so that the user only has to label a few clusters.

Drawbacks:

- Need training data from user / no instant gratification.
- More complicated to implement.

Advantages:

- Customised for the user.
- Not limited by external/not-personal training data.
- Use of other data (light/temperature/GPS/time/sound/camera).
- Possibly more accurate.
- Continuous re-training of the algorithm is possible.
- Accuracy improves over time as more data is available.
- Possibility to upload labeled data to central server and use that in future versions of the app.